# In Python Pandas, how to use like R dplyr mutate_each

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

In Python Pandas, I want to add columns by executing multiple aggregate functions on multiple columns like R dplyr mutate_each.
For example, Can Python Pandas realize the same processing as the following R script?

```
R dplyr :

 iris %>%
   group_by(Species) %>%
   mutate_each(funs(min, max, mean), starts_with("Sepal"))
```

However, I was able to achieve the same processing as mutate with Pandas.
As shown in the code below, I could execute one aggregate function and add one column.

```
R dplyr :

 iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(MaxSepalLen = max(Sepal.Length))

Python Pandas :

 iris.assign(MaxSepalLen = iris.groupby("Species")["Sepal.Length"].transform('max'))
```

Answer (score 1):

With Pandas, this can be accomplished in a more lenghty way.

First, let's prepare the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris_data = load_iris()
iris = pd.DataFrame(iris_data.data, columns = [c[0:3] + c[6] for c in iris_data.feature_names])
iris['Species'] = iris_data.target_names[iris_data.target]
```

Now we can imitate the `mutate_each` pipeline:

```
# calculate the aggregates
pivot = iris.groupby("Species")[iris.columns[iris.columns.str.startswith('sepal')]
                               ].aggregate(['min', 'max', np.mean])
# name the aggregates
pivot.columns = pivot.columns.get_level_values(0) + pivot.columns.get_level_values(1)
# merge aggregates with the original dataframe
new_iris = iris.merge(pivot, left_on='Species', right_index=True)
```

The `pivot` table is really a small pivot table:

```
            seplmin  seplmax  seplmean  sepwmin  sepwmax  sepwmean
Species                                                           
setosa          4.3      5.8     5.006      2.3      4.4     3.418
versicolor      4.9      7.0     5.936      2.0      3.4     2.770
virginica       4.9      7.9     6.588      2.2      3.8     2.974
```

And the `new_iris` is a 150x11 table with all columns from `iris` and `pivot` combined, identical to what `dplyr` outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

`mutate_each` is superseded by `mutate` and `across`.

You can try this in python:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, group_by, starts_with, mutate, across, max, min, mean
>>> from datar.datasets import iris
>>> 
>>> iris >> \
...    group_by(f.Species) >> \
...    mutate(across(starts_with("Sepal"), [min, max, mean]))
     Sepal_Length  Sepal_Width  Petal_Length  Petal_Width    Species  Sepal_Length_1  Sepal_Length_2  Sepal_Length_3  Sepal_Width_1  Sepal_Width_2  Sepal_Width_3
        <float64>    <float64>     <float64>    <float64>   <object>       <float64>       <float64>       <float64>      <float64>      <float64>      <float64>
0             5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2     setosa             4.3             5.8           5.006            2.3            4.4          3.428
1             4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2     setosa             4.3             5.8           5.006            2.3            4.4          3.428
2             4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2     setosa             4.3             5.8           5.006            2.3            4.4          3.428
3             4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2     setosa             4.3             5.8           5.006            2.3            4.4          3.428
..            ...          ...           ...          ...        ...             ...             ...             ...            ...            ...            ...
4             5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2     setosa             4.3             5.8           5.006            2.3            4.4          3.428
145           6.7          3.0           5.2          2.3  virginica             4.9             7.9           6.588            2.2            3.8          2.974
146           6.3          2.5           5.0          1.9  virginica             4.9             7.9           6.588            2.2            3.8          2.974
147           6.5          3.0           5.2          2.0  virginica             4.9             7.9           6.588            2.2            3.8          2.974
148           6.2          3.4           5.4          2.3  virginica             4.9             7.9           6.588            2.2            3.8          2.974
149           5.9          3.0           5.1          1.8  virginica             4.9             7.9           6.588            2.2            3.8          2.974

[Groups: Species (n=3)]
[150 rows x 11 columns]
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.